# InvalidOperationException: No IAuthenticationSignInHandler is configured to handle sign in for the scheme: MyCookieAuthenticationScheme

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x) to add Cookie Authentication to my site.

So far I have added the following:

> Invoke the UseAuthentication method in the Configure method of the
>   Startup.cs file:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

> Invoke the AddAuthentication and AddCookie methods in the
>   ConfigureServices method of the Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddAuthentication("MyCookieAuthenticationScheme")
    .AddCookie(options => {
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Forbidden/";
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Unauthorized/";
});
```

In my login code I then have

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCookieAuthenticationScheme", principal);
```

`principle` is a `ClaimsPrincipal`.

When I login to my site and call the line above I get the error:

> InvalidOperationException: No IAuthenticationSignInHandler is
>   configured to handle sign in for the scheme:
>   MyCookieAuthenticationScheme

What have I missed out?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You said you wanted the default scheme to be "MyCookieAuthenticationScheme" (that's the first argument to `AddAuthentication`) but you didn't add an authentication handler with that name. When you called `AddCookies`, you added the handler with the scheme "Cookies" (that's the default).

You need to change your code to:

```
services.AddAuthentication("MyCookieAuthenticationScheme")
    .AddCookie("MyCookieAuthenticationScheme", options => 
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Forbidden/";
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Unauthorized/";
    });
```

See this article to better understand the primitives:

https://digitalmccullough.com/posts/aspnetcore-auth-system-demystified.html

Comment: Thank You! I've been trying to figure this out most of the day. Lots of examples out there but they miss out the authentication handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the place of call `services.AddAuthentication(` This helped me.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(new HowResolveDependencies());

    services.AddTransient<IExceptionHandler, ExceptionToResponseWriter>();

    builder.Populate(services);

    services.AddAuthentication(AuthConsts.MainAuthScheme)
                 .AddCookie(
    ...
}
```

In my project, placing `services.AddAuthentication` before `builder.Populate(services)` solved the problem.